# Warp images using motion maps generated by opticalFlowLKDoG (Matlab 2015A)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, opticalflow

This question is based on a modified Matlab code from the online documentation for the optical flow system objects in version 2015a as appears in [opticalFlowLK class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/opticalflowlk-class.html)

```
clc; clearvars; close all;
inputVid = VideoReader('viptraffic.avi');
opticFlow = opticalFlowLKDoG('NumFrames',3);
inputVid.currentTime = 2;
k = 1;
while inputVid.currentTime<=2 + 1/inputVid.FrameRate
 frameRGB{k} = readFrame(inputVid);
 frameGray{k} = rgb2gray(frameRGB{k});    
 flow{k} = estimateFlow(opticFlow,frameGray{k});
 k = k+1;
end
```

By looking at flow{2}.Vx and flow{2}.Vy I get the motion maps U and V that describe the motion from frameGray{1} to frameGray{2}.

Iwant to use flow{2}.Vx and flow{2}.Vy directly on the data in frameGray{1} in order to warp frameGray{1} to appear visually similar to frameGray{2}.

I tried this code:

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:size(frameGray{1},2), 1:size(frameGray{1},1));
frameGray1Warped = interp2(double(frameGray{1}) , x-flow{2}.Vx , y-flow{2}.Vy);
```

But it doesn't seem to do much at all except ruin the image quality (but the objects don't display any real motion towards their locations in frameGray{2}.

I added 3 images showing the 2 original frames followed by frame 1 warped using the motion field to appear similar to frame 2:

[image: frame 1]

[image: frame 2]

[image: frame 1 warped to 2]

It can be seen easily that frame 1 warped to 2 is essentially frame 1 with degraded quality but the cars haven't moved at all. That is - the location of the cars is the same: look at the car closest to the camera with respect to the road separation line near it; it's virtually the same in frame 1 and frame 1 warped to 2, but is quite different in frame 2.

Comment: Can you post 2 consecutive images and the results you get with them? Its harder to help if you if we can not run it

Comment: Post images we can download. It might be that the flow is too small to begin with so that we warp there is barely any perceivable motion. You will degrade the image quality when you warp anyways.  This is good. This is how you detect moving things. Bad areas in the warped images means interesting things (if the flow is accurate).

Comment: Look at the car closest to the camera: in frame 1 it just reaches the road separation line and by frame 2 it crossed part of it. But the warped version of 1 to 2 keeps it at exactly the same position with respect to the separation line as in frame 1. No need to download the images to appreciate this difference. I'll edit the question